# Who were the 80 people that Loki killed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, loki

In *The Avengers* (2012), during the first meeting aboard the helicarrier, Thor warns Bruce Banner to mind his manners when speaking of Loki, because he's Thor's brother, to which Black Widow replies:

> He killed eighty people in two days.

Thor responds, *"He's adopted" [Insert laugh here].*

I assume Loki killed the guy whose eye he scanned and/or scooped out, and I know that Hawkeye killed a couple of people, but what about the other 77 or so people?

Who are these eighty people, and when did Loki kill them?

Comment: Might've been in the base collapse, but I don't remember any references.

Comment: Helps to actually _watch_ the film :P

Comment: Hey @WadCheber, let me know if you're looking for something more than the answer below. :-)

Comment: @Praxis -  I forgot all about this question.

Comment: @WadCheber : No worries, just wanted to make sure I was providing what you wanted.  Cheers.  :-)

Comment: Incidentally, I thought the line "He's adopted" was very cruel and somewhat inconsistent with the way Thor talked of Loki in the first film. It was a really cheap way to get a laugh which wasn't really in sync with how they portrayed  their relationship...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The toll likely includes those trapped in the collapse of the base at the start of the film, which Loki caused. Here is some dialogue from the script:

```
       AGENT PHIL COULSON

                      (WALKIE TALKIE)
       Director? Director Fury, do you copy?

                      NICK FURY
       The Tesseract is with the hostile
       force. I have men down. Hill?

      INT. P.E.G.A.S.U.S. TUNNEL ­ NIGHT

      Agent Hill climbs out her JEEP, which is sandwiched in, but
      luckily, not her.

       AGENT MARIA HILL
       A lot of men still under, don't know
       how many survivors.

      EXT. DESERT ­ NIGHT
```

The eighty victims probably included **"the men still under"** of which there were **"a lot"**.